# Does "give" as in "capacity to bend" derive from "to give" or another word?

Tags: etymology

I looked up the [etymology of "give"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=give&searchmode=none) on etymonline and it didn't say anything about the noun form. When I say the noun form, I'm speaking about "give" used in this context:

> The building foundation has some give to mitigate the effects of earthquakes.

Comment: It's a battle metaphor idiom. The loser _gives in_ to the winner. The vanquished _gives way_ to the victor. When something solid is said to _give, give in,_ or _give way,_ it's bending. And it's the same _give,_ just metaphorically used. [Metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) are awfully common in every language, including English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OED says that the noun *give* derives from the verb, and means:

> The action, fact, or quality of ‘giving’ (cf. sense 40 of the vb.); a yielding, giving way.

And where the referenced sense 40 is:

> **40**. *intr*. To yield, give way.
>
> - a. To yield to pressure or strain.
> - b. Of a joint, the nerves: To lose tension, to become relaxed, to fail.
> - c. (Of persons): To accommodate one’s attitude *to*; (of a dress) to adjust itself *to* (the varying curves of the figure). Also, to allow free play, yield *to*. Also, to give ground, draw back.
> - d. To be affected by atmospheric influences;
>
>   - (a).of colours, to fade;
>   - (b).to deliquesce, effloresce, soften, or deteriorate, from the effect of damp;
>   - (c).to become damp, (appear to) exude moisture, as a stone floor after a thaw (see **eve** *v*.<sup>2</sup>);
>   - (d).of timber, to shrink from dryness.
> - e. Of frosty weather: To relax its severity, to become mild; to thaw.
> - f. ***what gives?***: what is happening? (freq. as a question or merely as a form of greeting); so ***what gives with*** (someone or something)? = what is happening to?; what is (he, etc.) doing? (Cf. G. *was gibt’s*?) colloq. (orig. *U.S.*).

You probably should not consider Etymonline, which is mostly just cribbed from the OED anyway, to be a one-stop shopping center for these researches.